# jquery.flot - load charts on timer

Tags: jquery, setinterval, flot

I have a list of pages (Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, Page3.aspx) which by **jquery.flot** are plotted.
I want to display the page in sequence inside another page (Default.aspx).

To do this I call a method jquery load() on the timer.
**Image: [filelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ1iS.png)**

All is well as long as the list of pages is over. After this first page is called again (Page1.aspx) and the graphics look bad.

**Image: [Top - first call Page1.aspx, Bottom - second call Page1.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv2hY.png)**

```
var filelist = ["Page1.aspx","Page2.aspx","Page3.aspx"]; 
var fileIndex = 0;
function LoadFile() {
    if (fileIndex > filelist.length - 1) {
        fileIndex = 0;
    }

    $('#content').load("/Pages/" + filelist[fileIndex], ContentLoaded).show();
    fileIndex++;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var chengeFileTimer = $.timer(10000, LoadFile, false);
    LoadFile();
});
```

I have tried several types of charts - the situation does not change.

*Sorry for my English.*

Comment: Was does `ContentLoaded` stand for?

Comment: `ContentLoaded` only checks for errors in the loaded page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like on the second time you load Page1 (which is then page 4) you get 4 times the values from Page1 but most of them invisible.

Do you reuse variables for the data or the plot? The problem should go away if your clear all data and do a fresh plot on every page load.

Comment: I reuse variable data, but before every `$ ('# content').load()` clears it `data = {'charts': [], 'ticks': []};` On each page, I create a new `$. Plot ()`
I would not ask this question and would simply reload the site (window.location.reload()) as soon as the end list, but a similar problem occurs when there are two very similar pages (graphics type, connected components and used selectors).

Comment: There is no `charts` property in flot. Could you post your full code (maybe as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I think I understand. 
It was not properly connected to the loaded pages components **jquery.flot** When these components are connected again - there is such a mistake. Thanks!